# Proving that the volume of a unit ball is bounded by $c (\frac{c'}{d})^{\frac{d}{2}}$

Tags: polytopes, convex-geometry

Given that $B^d \subseteq \sqrt{d}B_1^d$, how do I use this to prove that the unit ball is bounded by $c (\frac{c'}{d})^{\frac{d}{2}}$ where $c, c'$ is some constant and $c, c' > 0$. Here $B^d$ is the unit ball and $B_1^d$ is a cross-polytope. The volume of $\sqrt{d}B_1^d = d^{\frac{d}{2}}2^d(d!)^{-1}$. What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: The explicit computation of the involved volumes is not that hard, but the first thought goes to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stirling's approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) implies $$0<\sqrt{2\pi} d^{d+1/2}e^{-d} \leq d!~~,$$
and we have
\begin{eqnarray}
vol(B^d)&\leq&vol(\sqrt{d}B_1^d)\\
&=&\frac{d^{\frac{d}{2}}2^d}{d!}\\
&\leq&\frac{d^{\frac{d}{2}}2^d}{\sqrt{2\pi} d^{d+1/2}e^{-d}}\\
&=&\frac{2^de^d}{\sqrt{2\pi} d^{d/2+1/2}}\\
&\leq&\frac{2^de^d}{\sqrt{2\pi} d^{d/2}}\\
&=&\frac{(4e^2)^{d/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} d^{d/2}}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\Big(\frac{4e^2}{d}\Big)^{d/2},
\end{eqnarray}

$\therefore~c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $c'=4e^2$.